# Acceptable level of mAP in computer vision applied to health applications

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, timeseries-segmentation, average-precision

**EDIT:**

This question is meant for those who previously understand what mAP means but for contextualizing this question properly, it is the mean average precision as defined by Microsoft COCO i.e. the mean between all classes and all IoU thresholds from 0.5 to 0.95 in 0.05 intervals, of the average precision from the precision-recall curve associated with a Computer Vision model in the context of an object detection task An object will be considered as detected when a bounding box prediction has an IoU above or equal to the given IoU threshold with a ground truth bounding box

---

I am trainig convolutional methods for detecting dental features in radiographs and trying to get the highest mAP by fine tuning, training new models and improving the ground truth labels by hiring specialists to apply stronger criteria for accepting ground truth label

The problem is, I do not have good reference on which is a good level of mAP In classification it is a standard to have over 90% of accuracy, but in object detection and segmentation there does not seem to be similar standards or criteria Moreover I must give some kind of metric for adverticing and validation as my bussiness accelerator is asking me to prove and measure my progress properly I have seen that the best models does not get much more than 75 mAP in publicly available datasets but I do not know if that is neither an 'acceptable' nor a 'good' level

What reference could I use to get this kind of standard and verify that I have reached something like a 'good level'?

Comment: What is mAP? ???

Comment: https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173